# POST login data which has Identity server assigning random ID - Not able to test API using postman

Tags: api, identityserver3

*Steps*

## Using Chrome Postman url - www.test.com/identity/custom/login (sorry cannot give actual URL as it is against company policy)

Note :- Identity server generates the above id every time when user clicks on login

Now when I use Chrome Postman and Post taking id from log in URL to test POST API I get 200 ok, but I am not logged in.)

Any pointer guys on how to handle ID generated by Identity server (.net frame work)

I need to get this working in order to perform load test and Login is important before I am attaching screen shot of my Postman screen

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do not go directly to the login view. You use the `/authorize` endpoint to initiate a login flow which will render the login view for you - given you gave it valid parameters.